# how to compare two column and copy the value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm trying to figure out how to write compare code. I have two sheets', sheet1 and sheet2.

in sheet1 have five digits id numbers in column A, in sheet2 have same five digits id number in column C, but in sheet2 the id number is not the same row as column A in sheet1, they are differents row.

I'm trying to figure out how to make comparisons in sheet1 column A to search for a match in ANY row in sheet2 column B then copy the value from the same row in sheet2 Column C to sheet1 column D!

this is my own testing code but is not working.

```
Sub FindStuff()

        Dim lr As Long
        Dim i As Integer

lr = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lr

If UCase(Sheet2.Cells(1, 3).Value) = UCase(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    Sheet2.Cells(14, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Offset(, 5).Value
      End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you post has both syntax error and logic error, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do. Can you post an workbook example?
I changed your formula with Vlookup in the code, you can test and let me know if this is what you need.

```
Sub MatchValues()
Dim ws1     As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lr      As Long
Dim r       As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
lr = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
Cells(r, 4) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws2.Cells(r, 3).Value, _
ws1.Range("A:A"), 1, 0)
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```